# XML Namespace & XML Task

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an XML file, which has a namespace with an XSD defined as:

```
<RootElement xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/xyz" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/xyz/XMLSchema-instance">
```

The XML is received from a vendor, and I have to perform a schema check, before proceeding with the processing. The schema check is done with `XML Task` component in `SSIS`. In the `XML Task` I define the location of the `XML` file, as well as the location of the `XSD`.

If the local version of `XSD` is different from the one that is referred to via `xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/xyz"` in the XML namespace, would the `SSIS` `XML Task` fail the schema check due to this difference? In other words, which one has the priority to check against; the local XSD file, or the one contained in the namespace URI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSIS **XML Source Adapter** is not doing any validation against an XSD.

1. SSIS is using its own local XSD file to describe structure, data types, and their mapping to SSIS data types of the input XML.
2. The XSD file referred inside the input XML file has a completely different role. SSIS XML Source Adapter is not using it.

SSIS XML Source Adapter is used for shredding of hierarchical XML into a rectangular/relational format. The adapter needs its own XSD file.

SSIS XML Task, operation Validation, will use an XSD file that is provided as a parameter to the task. It should be an XSD file on the file system. SSIS run-time servers not necessarily have access to the Internet via HTTP protocol. The actual namespace value is just for uniqueness. There is an additional optional schema location attribute that specifies XSD location: `xsi:schemaLocation="whatever.xsd"`

Comment: you are right, this component does not validate the schema. Instead, the `XML Task` does. But the question would be the same. Which XSD will be used in validation, the one that specified in the XML Task, or the one in the namespace? what is the role of the one that comes within the namesapce?

Comment: @khidirsanosi, I updated the answer. Please connect with me on LinkedIn.

Comment: I updated the question, replacing `XML Source Editor` with `XML Task`

Comment: @khidirsanosi, I updated the answer again. Waiting for you on LinkedIn.